# Object Reference Problem in Object Cache System

Tags: object, caching, reference, freepascal

I´m trying to create an object cache system, the languange i´m using is freepascal, but i think this problem will happen in other languages to.

The problem i´m facing is when i will remove an object from cache and this object is referenced by another object in the cache, so i´ll end up with an invalid reference.

I know the only way is to clean the reference in the remaining object when i´m about to remove one from the cache. When i have a few number of this cross references in chache this is not dificult to do.

But when the system grows it become a nightmare, so how can i keep track of the objects who is referencing the one i´m about to remove from cache and clean this dead references ?

Is there some well known techinique to do this without demanding a lot of lookups in the cache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your cache can't check if there are still references to your objects or when an object is not needed anymore and can be freed. The code that uses these objects is responsible for not holding any references to them an longer than necessary. And that is the only code that knows when an object can be freed.

Comment: @Rudy Now you point me another problem that i´ll have to solve, but maybe the solution for this question solves both. My question was not about "client" code that uses the objects in cache, is the references inside the cache, Let´s say that i have many Person objects in cache and many Order objects in cache, so each Order point to a Person as the customer, or/and the seller and so on. if i delete a Person, how can i know witch Orders is pointing to this person to clean this references.

Comment: You should not delete a Person if there are still Orders pointing to it. How do you know? By a proper program design. Your cache won't solve this. Recommended reading: [Memory Management](http://www.blurb.com/b/8809184-delphi-memory-management) by Dalija Prasnikar.

Comment: Thanks i´ll take a look !